# How to talk to a database from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, mysql

I want variables from my Javascript functions to be recorded in a database on my server and then posted back onto the html page. I know this may be easy with the POST and GET method, but I've been reading and I'm stumped. So if anyone could lead me to a sample that shows how to do this or show me here in an example of one that would help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use some form of server-side scripting language (such as [PHP](http://php.net/)) to capture the data sent from JavaScript (presumably via means of AJAX's XMLHttpRequest object) and insert it in the database.

i.e.: There's no means of directly communicating with MySQL from JavaScript itself - you need to use a server-side scripting language to do this.

Comment: i know this :P im looking for examples of ajax that can better explain it

Comment: @Hijumper Are you using an existing JavaScript framework such as jQuery? If so, it has some [good documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that should help.

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna read into [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) which uses the [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/) object to do exactly that.

Using this you can send data to and from a server side script. So that way you could "insert variables into database."

Comment: ive read into it, but nothing really sinks in, its just too bland for me to read it there

Comment: @Hijumper:Firstly, which server side language are you familiar with?